# Correct format string for String.format or similar

Tags: java, string, formatting

I'm sure I've seen `String.format` used like this before:

```
String.format("Some {1}, {2}, {3}", var1, var2, var3);
```

Does this ring any bells for anyone? Maybe I'm thinking of C#, is there a way of achieving the same in java?

I know you can do something like:

```
String.format("Some %s, %d, %s", aString, aNumber, aString)
```

but the syntax I'm after is for the former...

Answer (score 65, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html), which uses a given format and input parameters, e.g.

```
MessageFormat.format("Some {0}, {1}, {2}", var1, var2, var3);
```

And as already mentioned, [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) can still do the job using the alternate syntax, but it is less powerful in functionality and not what you requested.

Comment: Did some research: String.format is actually newer than MessageFormat. They do use different methods under the hood but don't differ much in overall functionality. String.format thus is said to be quicker.

Comment: Nice. Exists in Android as well. A very simple way of formatting. Not needing to provide the type of the input is an advantage.

Answer (score 21):

I do not like to specify both index of parameter or its type - mainly when throwing exception and preparing message for it. I like way SLF4j does it. So I wrapped org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter like this:

```
public static String subst(String string, Object...objects) {
    return MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(string, objects).getMessage();
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
public void main(String[] args) {
    throw new RuntimeException(MyUtils.subst("Problem with A={} and B={}!", a, b));
}
```

Comment: For most cases (one or 2 parameters), you can also use directly : MessageFormatter.format("Problem with A={} and B={}!", a, b); (still org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter )

Answer (score 15):

Yes, that's the typical [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) string of *C#*. In Java, you can use the latter, that is, `String.format("%s %d %d", ...)`.

An *alternative* is to use `MessageFormat.format("Some {0}, {1}, {2}", var1, var2, var3)`, which uses the .NET curly braces notation, as mentioned by @Tobias, though it requires you to import [`java.text.MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html). They are also more appropriate for when you are dealing with localized resources, where you typically have external `.properties` files with messages in the format `Error {0} ocurred due to {1}`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use Java's String Templates feature.
It is described in [JEP 430](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430), and it appears in JDK 21 as a preview feature.  Here is an example use:

```java
String s = STR."Some \{aString}, \{aNumber}, \{aString}";
```

Java's string templates are more versatile, and much safer, than features in other languagues such as C#'s string interpolation and Python's f-strings.
For example, string concatenation or interpolation makes SQL injection attacks possible:

```java
String query = "SELECT * FROM Person p WHERE p.last_name = '" + name + "'";
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
```

but this variant (from JEP 430) prevents SQL injection:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = DB."SELECT * FROM Person p WHERE p.last_name = \{name}";
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to use empty placeholders (without positions), you could write a small utility around `Message.format()`, like this

```
    String format(String s, Object... var2) {
        int i = 0;
        while(s.contains("{}")) {
            s = s.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("{}"), "{"+ i++ +"}");
        }
        return MessageFormat.format(s, var2);
    }
```

And then, can use it like,

```
format("Some {} {} {}", var1, var2, var3);
```