# Condensing multiple System.out.prinln() into one

Tags: java

I have

```
        for( int x = 0; x < rp.studentRecords.length; x++){
        System.out.println("Student name: " +rp.studentRecords[x].getName());
        System.out.println("Major: "+ rp.studentRecords[x].getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("Age: "+ rp.studentRecords[x].getName());
        System.out.println("Year " +rp.studentRecords[x].getYear());
        System.out.println("Credits Earned: "+ rp.studentRecords[x].getCredits());
        System.out.println("Remaining Credits: "+ rp.studentRecords[x].getRemainingCredits());
        System.out.println("-------");
    }
```

and I need to condense those System.out.println()s into a single one.

Comment: You can output a new line with `"\n"`. Maybe also look at `String.format`.

Comment: also: ........... why?

Comment: Thanks Thilo! I can't bealive I forgot about that.

Comment: I believe that your best option is [MessageFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132604/correct-format-string-for-string-format-or-similar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could try is to use `String.format` like

```
String output = String.format ("Name: %s\nMajor: %s\nAge: %s", 
  rp.studentRecords[x].getName(),
  rp.studentRecords[x].getClass().getName(),
  rp.studentRecords[x].getAge());

// then print it out
System.out.println (output);
```